# HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(…) “deadlock” when there is no internet connection in .NET standard library calling from UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, dotnet-httpclient, .net-standard

I am developing a UWP application for a document management system. I am trying to open documents from my application. When I click the open document, It is going to download the document and then open in the default application. But the problem is document is not downloaded if the internet is a disconnect in the middle of the process. It means when `httpClient` is already called. My code is as following

```
   public async Task<DownloadFileDetail> DownloadFileAsync(int dmsFileId)
    {
        if (dmsFileId <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid DMS File Id");
        }
        try
        {
            return await Task.Run(async () =>
              {
                  DownloadFileDetail fileDetail = new DownloadFileDetail()
                  {
                      DocId = dmsFileId
                  };
                  string apiUrl = $"files/download/latest/{dmsFileId}";
                  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                  httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseApiUrl);
                  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {SessionStore.Instance.AuthToken}");
                  var response = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(apiUrl); --> gone deadlock
                  fileDetail.Content = response;
                  return fileDetail;
              });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return new DownloadFileDetail()
        {
            DocId = dmsFileId
        };
    }
```

Download process called as UWP->.NET Standard Library (holds above code). It will be great if someone helps me to solve the problem.

Thanks
ss

Update:
The above code is working on my laptop and not working on any other laptop in dev environment

Comment: Why are you using the `Task.Run` API to perform the download on a background thread? Also note that there is a [Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-5.0) property.

Comment: I tried timeout it was also not solve problem

Comment: Could you try adding `.ConfigureAwait(false);` to the end of both the await statements? The await might block your UI thread which causes the deadlock.

Comment: I will try above

Comment: Have you tried add `CancellationTokenSource` to make default timeout, if the request overtime， it will break automatically

Comment: I have tried all .ConfigureAwait(false); and CancellationTokenSource  and it is not working.

Comment: May be you need check if the network is available before send http request.

Comment: what makes you think it is a deadlock, specifically? something not completing is not the same as a deadlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when there is no internet connection in .NET standar library calling from UWP

If the deadlock only occurs in no internet connection environment, you could check if internet is available before sending http request. Please check this [`NetworkHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.connectivity.networkhelper?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable).

```
if (NetworkHelper.Instance.ConnectionInformation.IsInternetAvailable)
{
// sending the request.
}
```

Comment: deadlock start when the internet is a disconnect in the middle of httpclient makes a request. Imeans await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(apiUrl) already start.

Comment: above code is working in my one laptop but not another laptop, I tested it in 3 other laptops but fail all of them.

Comment: It contains  [`NetworkChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.connectivity.networkhelper.networkchanged?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable), you may cancel manually the request when network is not available.

Comment: Working machine throw Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EFE message when network is disconnect

Comment: which line throw this exception

Comment: var response = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(apiUrl). If you available then I can show via zoom

Comment: I am not understanding why It is working on my one laptop but not another laptop both has window 10 Pro and Enterprise(not working)

Comment: Why not place above code in the try catch block to a avoid app shut down?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224835/discussion-between-shyam-sundar-shah-and-nico-zhu-msft).

Comment: I passed as parameter cancellationtokensource  method and httprequest.GetStreamAsync uses cancellationtoken . Once the network changes I cancel the token but not work. I need to take care from other place.

Comment: I think use NetworkChanged  and cancel `GetStreamAsync ` is correct way , but I don't know why it could not stop with cancel token?

Comment: I will try it again by changing the variable scope. Thanks  Nico Zhu - MSFT

Answer (score -1):

First, remove the `Task.Run(async () => ...)` call:

```cs
try
{
  DownloadFileDetail fileDetail = new DownloadFileDetail()
  {
      DocId = dmsFileId
  };
  string apiUrl = $"files/download/latest/{dmsFileId}";
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseApiUrl);
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {SessionStore.Instance.AuthToken}");
  var response = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(apiUrl); --> gone deadlock
  fileDetail.Content = response;
  
  return fileDetail;
}
```

Comment: now that's done, add how you are calling that method please

Comment: I am calling from a browser with a custom protocol which opens our UWP app and then UWP starts downloading the file

Comment: make that entry point to that uwp method async and await the call to DownloadFileAsync. If you don't give more information on the surrounding code we can't help you.

Comment: It is working with any change in my laptop but not working on any other laptop.